# Is it possible to turn off ContextMenu option in Gong-Shell ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, contextmenu, windows-shell

https://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

I am using ShellListView of Gong-Shell. It's perfetly useful but I want to use my custom context menu on right click not the window system context menu.

[I don't want the context menu to pop up on right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqKjQ.jpg)

```cs
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  const int WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B;
            
  if (m.Msg == WM_CONTEXTMENU)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("WM_CONTEXTMENU");
      m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
  }
}
```

I tried hooking the System ContextMenu with the WndProc function, but it didn't work.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an official way to do it because the context menu is fully defined by the Shell Folder you're looking at which for most folders is created by the system. So, here's an unofficial and a bit hacky way:

First, declare the `IContextMenuModifier` interface:

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("26b79130-4c9f-4424-aefb-52cc63f4d3c6")]
public interface IContextMenuModifier
{
    [PreserveSig]
    HResult GetContextMenu(IContextMenu oldMenu, out IContextMenu menu);
}
```

Then, add an implementation of `IContextMenuModifier` to the `ShellBrowser` class and modify the `IServiceProvider.QueryService` implementation:

```
class ShellBrowser : IShellBrowser,
                  IContextMenuModifier,
                  etc..
{
  HResult IContextMenuModifier.GetContextMenu(IContextMenu oldMenu, out IContextMenu menu)
  {
      menu = new MyMenu(m_ShellView); // replace the default menu by a custom one
      return HResult.S_OK;
  }
  
  HResult Interop.IServiceProvider.QueryService(ref Guid guidService,
                                                ref Guid riid,
                                                out IntPtr ppvObject)
  {
      ... add this here so we support this IContextMenuModifier interface
      else if (riid == typeof(IContextMenuModifier).GUID)
      {
          ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IContextMenuModifier));
      }
      else
      {
          ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
          return HResult.E_NOINTERFACE;
      }
      return HResult.S_OK;
  }
}
```

And here is an implementation of `IContextMenu` that kills the menu underneath:

```
public class MyMenu : IContextMenu
{
    private readonly ShellView _shellView;

    public MyMenu(ShellView shellView)
    {
        _shellView = shellView;
    }

    public HResult QueryContextMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint indexMenu, int idCmdFirst, int idCmdLast, CMF uFlags)
    {
        // a bit rude, but I don't see any another way...
        DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        
        // create your own menu (or not)
        var menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.MenuItems.Add("hello world");
        menu.Show(_shellView, _shellView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        return HResult.S_OK;
    }

    public void InvokeCommand(ref CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici) { }
    public HResult GetCommandString(int idcmd, uint uflags, int reserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder commandstring, int cch) => HResult.E_NOTIMPL;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private extern static int DestroyMenu(IntPtr hMenu);
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the great solution. this is completely resolved. Maybe Did you also solved remove Coulmn header of ShellView? This doesn't work properly depending on the View style.

Comment: @Spiegel - not sure what you mean, you should ask another question